# Native file watcher executable is outdated warning in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Am getting this warning in Android Studio

> External file changes sync may be slow.
>     Native fille watcher executable is outdated

[image]

I checked for updates, used the `Install and Restart` option, but Android studio just disappears afterwards.When I restart my computer I still get the same warning and the update is not effected.
What is this warning about and how do I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem

Comment: Nope.It's still there.I think the problem is with the machine and not Android Studio per se.Am using a windows 7 desktop computer that has seen better days and I don't get the error or many others that I get on it on my newer windows 8 laptop.

Comment: I just clean some space in mobile its working.

Comment: i just remove the space in internal storage

Comment: Hahaha.Come on man, be specific.

Comment: Are using windows or Ubuntu machine for development

Comment: i am using windows i gave chmod +x to notifier64 its working now

Answer (score 2):

Do a simple thing go to android-studio/bin/fsnotifier64 and right click fsnotifier and in permission you will see allow executing just click on allow executing and all done